# Enumerating and do Calculations

Tags: r

If I have a data frame like this, which can be think as the responses of a survey for different respondents

```
Data = 
ID Q1 Q2 Q3
1  A1 B2 C3
2  A2 B1 C2
3  A1 B2 C3
...
```

and I also have the following score tables:

```
Q1 <- (c("A1", 10, "A2", 20, ...))
Q2 <- (c("B1", 10, "B2", 20, ...))
Q3 <- (c("C1", 10, "C2", 20, ...))
```

which mean that, if I choose "A1" in Q1, I get 10 marks, if I choose "B2" in Q2, I get 20 marks more, and if I choose "C1" in Q3, That is also 10 marks, the total score I got would be:
10 (A1) + 20 (B2) + 10 (C1) = 40

And now for every row in the Data, I need to calculation the total score by summing the scores for each columns according to the score tables.

Can any one suggest me how I can use a simple code to do so? 
For now I can only think of make the score tables in to a Xx2 Matrices, and use a lot of nested-if and for-loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df <- read.table(text="ID Q1 Q2 Q3
1  A1 B2 C3
2  A2 B1 C2
3  A1 B2 C3",header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

scores <- list(
Q1 = c("A1", 10, "A2", 20, "A3", 30),
Q2 =c("B1", 30, "B2", 10, "B3", 20),
Q3 =c("C1", 10, "C2", 30, "C3", 20)
)

#lookup table
scores <- do.call("cbind",scores)

#match
m <- apply(df[,-1],2,match,table=scores)

#look up
points <- matrix(as.numeric(scores[m+1]),ncol=ncol(df)-1)

#sum for each ID
result <- cbind(df,Score=rowSums(points))

  ID Q1 Q2 Q3 Score
1  1 A1 B2 C3    40
2  2 A2 B1 C2    80
3  3 A1 B2 C3    40
```

Answer (score 1):

The data:

```
Data <- read.table(text = "ID Q1 Q2 Q3
1  A1 B2 C3
2  A2 B1 C2
3  A1 B2 C3", header = TRUE)

Q1 <- c("A1", 10, "A2", 20)
Q2 <- c("B1", 10, "B2", 20)
Q3 <- c("C1", 10, "C2", 20)
```

First, a list of the `Q` objects is created:

```
Qlist <- list(Q1 = Q1, Q2 = Q2, Q3 = Q3)
```

Now, `sapply` could be used:

```
cbind(Data,
      QSum = rowSums(sapply(names(Qlist),
                            function(q)
                              as.numeric(Qlist[[q]][match(Data[[q]],
                                                          Qlist[[q]]) + 1])), 
                     na.rm = TRUE))
```

The output:

```
  ID Q1 Q2 Q3 QSum
1  1 A1 B2 C3   30
2  2 A2 B1 C2   50
3  3 A1 B2 C3   30
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll use the "scores" as Roland has chosen. Since you mention that you could alter the scores table to a 2x2 matrix, I provide the solution below which differs from the other 2 in having a different data structure for scores.

Allow me to explain me logic before I provide you the code:

1. I wish to process df row by row
2. For each row, I wish to use the score for the answer chosen per question
3. I wish to sum it up

Based on 2, I feel the need for an associative array which I can index based on question number & entered answer. Hence I create the following representation for scores:

```
> scores <- list(
+                 Q1 = list(A1=10,A2=20,A3=30),
+                 Q2 = list(B1=30,B2=10,B3=20),
+                 Q3 = list(C1=10,C2=30,C3=20)
+               )
```

Basically, scores is now a list of lists. By doing this, I can do the following:

```
> scores[["Q1"]][["A1"]]
[1] 10
```

Now all I need to do is figure out a way to parameterise "Q1" & "A1" above.

The data frame "df" is as follows:

```
> df
  ID Q1 Q2 Q3
1  1 A1 B2 C3
2  2 A2 B1 C2
3  3 A1 B2 C3
```

What I care about, is each row without the ID column. So, I extract just that:

```
> df[1,-1]
  Q1 Q2 Q3
1 A1 B2 C3
```

By now you can see that I need to pick the column name for the first index into scores & the value in the row for the 2nd index. Thus, if I can get scores[[column-M]][[row-NvalueForColumn-M]] then I can sum them up.

The column names are easily obtained thus:

```
> columnNames <- colnames(df[1,-1])
> columnNames
[1] "Q1" "Q2" "Q3"
```

So your final piece of code to do the necessary logic is this:

```
> columnNames <- colnames(df[1,-1])
> score <- c(0,0,0)
> for (i in 1:length(df[1,-1]))
+ {
+     for (j in 1:length(columnNames))
+     {
+         score[i] <- score[i] + scores[[columnNames[j]]][[df[i,-1][[columnNames[j]]]]]
+     }
+ }
> final <- cbind(df,score)
> final
  ID Q1 Q2 Q3 score
1  1 A1 B2 C3    40
2  2 A2 B1 C2    80
3  3 A1 B2 C3    40
>
```

I believe the above code can be reduced by at least 5 lines (using rowsums, etc). I am sure experienced folks like Sven could improve the piece of code above to a nifty couple of lines. Would appreciate input.